# View Agent Install breaks IE8 on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, vmware-view

I'm playing with a Windows 7 virtual desktop. The virtual desktop was built on a vSphere 4U1 infrastructure and created from a Windows 7 ISO.

I've installed the OS and patched it, installed VMware Tools etc. and all good.

I wanted to add this to our View 4 infrastructure, so tried to install the View agent. (VMware-viewagent-4.0.0-210939.exe)

I had problems with this install similar to http://www.thinkvirt.com/?q=node/132, followed the suggestions there but couldn't get it to install.

I restarted the install, but rather than a typical install, selected Custom and dropped the Composer Agent as taht seemed to be the bit causing the grief.

Once installed and rebooted I then found IE 8 wouldn't work. IE8 starts, and at this point the home page is external, asks for the proxy credentials, if I enter them or cancel the OS reports that IE has stopped working and it crashes.

If I then remove the View Agent and reboot it IE8 starts working again.

Anyone come across anything similar?

Comment: Are you linked to ToreTrygg? This is a direct lift of a question _verbatim_ from vmware communities, like dozens of recent q's from TT & Mads. What's going on here? This is beginning to seem like a concerted spam effort.

Comment: I've asked this question here cause it seems like noone knows the answear on vmware community, and I'd like to know how this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

With the realease of View 4.5, the new view agent (VMware-viewagent-4.5.0-293049), I install it over win 7, and the IE doesn´t break.
I proveed in three virtual machines and work ok.CesarV